# Best way to handle one-time payments with STRIPE webhooks in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using STRIPE as my payment processor, in an REACT + nodeJS app. I already have something that already works, but I would like some feedback, maybe I'm doing something wrong.
So... I have this Redirect-To-Checkout functionality thats made available by STRIPE, basically I redirect the user to this STRIPE page where all card-data (sensitive information) is processes in order for the payment to full-fill.

What I do in my nodeJS server part is the following:

1. Once the user acces the redirect to check-out page, I already create a PendingOrder, with the products selected by client (Here I save some information based on client/stripe payment-intent, in order to check in later steps)
2. Once webhook gives me the 'payment_intent.succeeded' I check for the payment-intent information to see if it exists in my PendingOrder collection, then proceed to add in to ConfirmedOrders and remove it from PendingOrders.

I have to do this whole process because Stripe no longer gives me access to some information I require when the user is checking-out his order(such as observation that the user has based on the type of service he chooses).

Are there any down-sides to this approach or is there any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You’re not really far from the best practices that Stripe recommends [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#fulfill). The only thing that I would change is listening to `checkout.session.completed` instead of the `payment_intent.succeeded` event. As of the latest API [version](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01), a PaymentIntent is no longer created upfront so a better to way to handle order fulfillment is to either store the Checkout Session ID (e.g. `cs_live_xxx`) or you could add some [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata) when creating the Checkout Session and use that instead to identify the order.

> I have to do this whole process because Stripe no longer gives me access to some information I require when the user is checking-out his order

As for this, I’m not sure what you mean, you can always use your app with the success page customization described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page) alongside webhooks. I wouldn’t use that to fulfill the order though since the user might close the page before the redirection completes which means that the fulfillment wouldn’t be done in that case. As such, webhooks are essential to order fulfillment.